# What is _score in ES/Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have this document in ES and I am looking at it through Kibana.

What does the _score field represent?

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 11,
    "successful": 11,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "order",
        "_type": "ACKNOWLEDGED",
        "_id": "9901234567",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "applicationCode": "SAPS00",
          "orderId": "9901234567",
          "status": "ACKNOWLEDGED",
          "orderUpdatedDateTime": "2018-07-08T10:12:21Z",
          "totals": {
            "orderShippingTaxAmount": 3.5,
            "orderSubtotalTaxAmount": 12.55,
            "grandTotalTaxAmount": 15
          },
          "orderLines": [
            {
              "lineId": "1",
              "unitPriceTaxAmount": 5.45,
              "totalPriceTaxAmount": 10.67,
              "lineShippingTaxAmount": null
            },
            {
              "lineId": "2",
              "unitPriceTaxAmount": 2.45,
              "totalPriceTaxAmount": 8.67,
              "lineShippingTaxAmount": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It indicates how well said document scored against your query.

Comment: this might be worth reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/relevance-intro.html#explain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `_score` in Elasticsearch is a way of determining how relevant a match is to the query. The default scoring function used by Elasticsearch is actually the default built in to Lucene which is what Elasticsearch runs under the hood. Here's an article that describes scoring fairly well.

https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/

> Elasticsearch runs Lucene under the hood so by default it uses
>   Lucene's Practical Scoring Function. This is a similarity model based
>   on Term Frequency (tf) and Inverse Document Frequency (idf) that also
>   uses the Vector Space Model (vsm) for multi-term queries.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Search Designed as  a Search Engine-like google.  "_score" is a metric represents the relevance of a match to your given filters (Similar to google page match score) of that document.

Documentation. : https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/elasticsearch-score/